# Laravel how to store premade and user made values in a queryable manner?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a table called `templates` which by default contains some premade templates. Each template belongs to a `category`. A `category` can have one or many templates.

Users can also create their own custom templates by modifying a premade template. What would be the best way to store this custom templates? Should i store this default templates in the same table with the premade ones?

This is what i have so far:

```
categories table
+---+----+
|id |name|
+---+----+
|1  |A   |
+---+----+
|2  |B   |
+---+----+   

users table
+---+-------+
|id |name   |
+---+-------+
|1  |Andrew |
+---+-------+
|2  |Joe    |
+---+-------+
|3  |Emma   |
+---+-------+

templates table
+---+------------+--------+-----------+
|id |category_id |user_id |properties |
+---+------------+--------+-----------+
|1  |1           |null    |[]         |
+---+------------+--------+-----------+
|2  |1           |2       |[]         |
+---+------------+--------+-----------+
|3  |2           |null    |[]         |
+---+------------+--------+-----------+
```

In this example the `templates` with "null" `user_id` are the default `templates` and can be seen by all users and the `templates` with a `user_id` can only be seen by that specific user.

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Why not go down the route of having a `premade_templates` table and a `custom_templates` table? That separates your logic a little better where you don't need to check ownership on the premade/default ones, but only on the custom ones

Comment: @AndyHolmes is having multiple tables considered a better route? If yes, can you please help me understand why? Wouldn't that mean that i'll have to have two Models aswell?

Comment: Depends what you mean by better, but its a separation of concerns, it reduces a check of ownership on every usage of a default/premade template and shifts that check to custom only. If your system grew large, it would be easier to manage.

Yeah you'd have 2 models in theory, the thought process behind my suggestion is that it seems unlikely that your custom implementations will have 2 columns only, and there's not much point bloating out a templates table with columns that should only be used on custom ones

Comment: The point that i forgot to mention is that i need the `category` in both cases. That means that i will have to still create a table similar to the one above for custom templates and that would defeat the whole purpose of reducing the number of columns/table :(

Comment: Not entirely, you could utilise a pivot table to make that work. But the point I'm trying to highlight is that it's very unlikely that your tables will remain as they are now over time, there is a good chance that other columns will need to be added for one instance, but not the other, so whilst it may not seem it now, it would be a good practice to separate them